# Get rid of anything outside brackets in string java

Tags: java, string

I have the following string

```
34rf;43jh<helloworld>guge73g34/
```

I basically want everything outside of "<" and ">" to be removed from the string so that it returns:

```
<helloworld>
```

How could I do this?

Comment: You tell us how you can do it.

Comment: I tried to take the index of "<" and ">" e.g x.substring(frame.indexOf("<"));
            x.substring(frame.indexOf(">")); but that just returned the random characters I dont want

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have only one "<" and ">" in your input?

Comment: < and > will always be there yes

Comment: Do you have idea of regex in java?

Answer (score 2):

I have a few suggestions, I'd probably do something like this

```
public static String parse(String in) {
  // Find the open '<'.
  int p1 = in.indexOf('<');
  // If we found an open less-then, check for next closing greater-then
  int p2 = (p1 < 0) ? -1 : in.indexOf('>', p1 + 1);
  if (p2 >= 0) {
    // Found it... return the sub-string.
    return in.substring(p1, p2 + 1);
  }
  // return the input? might want "" instead.
  return in;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions:

```
String str = "34rf;43jh<helloworld>guge73g34/";
Pattern bracketPattern = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>");
Matcher m = bracketPattern.matcher(str);
if (m.find())
  String match = m.group(1);
```

Comment: This is far nicer than the others. +1

Answer (score 2):

Oh you have zillion ways to achieve this... This is one way of achieving what you needed.

```
String input = "34rf;43jh<helloworld>guge73g34/";
int start = input.indexOf('<');
int end = input.indexOf('>');
System.out.println(input.substring(start, end+1));
```

This is another way of achieving the same using regular expressions and using replaceFirst method

```
System.out.println(input.replaceFirst(".*<", "<").replaceFirst(">.*", ">"));
```

However these two are not good candidates if you have more than one tag and you want to find all the tags. In that can you obviously have to go for a regular expression and using which you can find all tags. One of the answer below already shown how to do that so I'm not doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one "<" and one ">" you could use the String.split() method like so:

```
String myWord = myWord.split("<")[1];
myWord = myWord.split(">")[0];
myWord = "<" + myWord + ">";
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two goals here.

1) Locate the index of each bracket. Cosider the following code:

```
static String input = "34rf;43jh<helloworld>guge73g34/";
int firstBracketPosition = 0;
int lastBracketPosition = 0;

firstBracketPosition = input.indexOf("<");
lastBracketPosition = input.lastIndexOf(">");
```

The first three lines are variable declarations. The fourth line finds the first occurrence of "<", and returns the index. The fifth line finds the final occurrence of ">" and returns the index. Those indices are stored in their respective variables.

2) You want to grab the text in between the two brackets. (Inclusive of the brackets).
Consider the following code:

```
static String output = "";

output = input.substring(firstBracketPosition, lastBracketPosition + 1);
System.out.println(output);
```

The first line is a variable declaration. The second line takes the part of the input string between the two bracket indices, adding one to the final position to include the final bracket in the output string. The final line prints the value of `output`.

Using your supplied code, this program prints

```
<helloworld>
```